# How to make collision between a node that was hard-coded, (in swift file), and an node that was placed in the scene editor? - Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

We are trying to create a collision between the player, who's physics body (CategoryBitMask, CollisionBitMask, ContactTestBitMask) was programmed in the swift file, and the enemy that was placed in the scene editor and its physics body (CategoryBitMask = 2, CollisionBitMask = 4294967295 'default', ContactBitMask = 1). The code shown below shows what was tested but resulted in no collision.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class ClassicLevelScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    // Physics Bodies Setup
    let enemy:UInt32 = 2
    
    // Player Constant
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "car1")

    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        
        // Physics World
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

   
        // Set up player
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 30, y: -245)
        player.zPosition = Layers.cars
        player.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 80)
        player.name = "player"
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: player.texture!, size: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height))
        player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        player.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 7
        player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 1
        addChild(player)
}


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
      /* Player touches anything, game over */
        let contactA:SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
        let contactB:SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
        if  contactA.categoryBitMask == 2  || contactB.categoryBitMask == 2 {
        // execute code to respond to object hitting ground
            minusHeart()
            spikeSparkExplosion()
        }
    }
```

Comment: The following doesn't make sense.  if  contactA.categoryBitMask == 2  || contactB.categoryBitMask == 2 {}

Comment: You are not showing everything that you have.  How do you get the following?  player.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 7

Comment: `if  contactA.categoryBitMask == 2  || contactB.categoryBitMask == 2` That’s nonsense. I think you need to find out what a bitmask is.

Answer (score -1):

You likely have various issues.  First this is probably a typo:

```swift
        let contactA:SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB  // you meant bodyA?
        let contactB:SKPhysicsBody = contact.bodyB
```

Second, you don't seem overly clear about contacts vs collisions.  Collisions = objects bounce off each other.  Contacts = you get notified when objects touch.  From the code it seems like you want the latter, and you may not want the collisions at all.  Anyway you should have categories 1 and 2 for the category bitmasks (that part looks OK) and contact bit masks of 2 and 1 (respectively).  That is, your player has category 1, and you want to know when it touches something in category 2.  So the player's contact test bit mask should be 2 (you have it set to 1).

Comment: Yes thank you! It was a typo, it was supposed to be bodyA instead of bodyB. Thank you! 